# asp.net core project occurs MissingMethodException

Tags: asp.net-core, methodnotfound

I create a new project with ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Core). 
And it can work after building and running it.

I create a class library with .NET Core and move the files under Service folder in the web project to the library, then add the reference and change namespace in the controllers.

It occurs MissingMethodException after registering a new user.
Asp.net core project seems not able to use class library outside the web project.

The detailed message is as the below.

[image]

Comment: You move "the files" - what files are you talking about, exactly? The (C#?) source files, the compiled dll, or something else?

Comment: They are C# source files. 
IEmailSender.cs, ISmsSender.cs and MessageServices.cs.

Comment: With a class library, you either use a separate project within the same solution and add a reference to that project in the main project, or (when the library is a separate solution) you add a reference to the compiled dll. No need to copy source files.

Comment: The class library and main project are under the same solution.

Comment: I think this issue is related to  https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/245

Comment: I also post the questions on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5019#issuecomment-232687633 

and the answer is all project.json of the class libraries need to refer to the same version in 

"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
"version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
"type": "platform"
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core , everything is in form of nuget packages, hence you might have to create nuget package from the class library and then add it to the current solution.

Hope this information helps.